# Scroll and click - Not working for both Android and iOS on Appium tool with selenium java

Tags: java, android, ios, selenium, appium

I am trying to scroll and its not working for both Android and iOS, Can you please help me on this.

Look forward to hear back from you.

Did try with ScrollTO and ScrollToExact as both of them are deprecated now, so did try with this:

```
        String str = "CADILLAC";
        driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new  UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new  UiSelector().textContains(\""+str+"\").instance(0))").click();
```

Still does not work.

Did go through many blogs , videos , course content and material no one has explained or there a specific solution on how to handle this

Did try with below,still gets the error

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().resourceId(\"current_value_tv\").text(\"All Makes\")").click();
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.TextView\").text(\"AUSTIN HEALEY\")").click();
```

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not
>   provide any stacktrace information)
>           Command duration or timeout: 45 milliseconds
>           Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
>           System info: host: 'NCA1026471', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_91'
>           Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
>           Capabilities [{app=C:\Appium\workspace\Lokesh\app\app-release.apk,
>   appPackage=au.com.carsguide, rotatable=true,
>   networkConnectionEnabled=true,  noReset=true, warnings={},
>   handlesAlerts=true, deviceName=Carsguide Product,  version=0.17.0,
>   platform=ANDROID,  appActivity=au.com.carsguide.activity.HomeActivity,
>   desired= {app=C:\Appium\workspace\Lokesh\app\app-release.apk, 
>   appPackage=au.com.carsguide,
>   appActivity=au.com.carsguide.activity.HomeActivity, noReset=true,
>   platformVersion=5.0, browserName=, platformName=Android,
>   deviceName=Carsguide Product, device=Android}, acceptSslCerts=true,
>   platformVersion=21, automationName=selendroid, browserName=selendroid,
>   takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=android, 
>   device=Android}]
>           Session ID: e90cac4d-38aa-99fd-2dd2-70cc09a0e717
>          *** Element info: {Using=-android uiautomator,        value=UiSelector().resourceId("current_value_tv").text("All Makes")}
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below code, i was trying this code on settings page..

```
AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(""), cap1);

driver.scrollTo("About phone");
```

Pass the String which is present in the bottom of your app page.

```
driver.scrollTo("Enter your value");
```

Use appropriate wait Statements.

Comment: i @Deepak_Mahalingam have tried this earlier as well and does not work. below is my code, is it working fine for you? are u able to scroll. And why do we need this "AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(""), cap1);" I am using public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver; should it be fine?

Comment: @Test
 public void test() throws InterruptedException {
  
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("All Makes")).click();
  driver.scrollTo("AUDI");

Comment: @Lokesh : after the click operation just add wait statement,.. try using following code

Comment: @Lokesh : after the click operation just add wait statement,.. try using following code
DesiredCapabilities cap1= new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap1.setCapability("deviceName", "devicename");
    cap1.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.4");
    cap1.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap1.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");
AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap1);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("All Makes")).click(); 
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.scrollTo("AUDI");

Comment: Still no luck, basically what i am trying to achive is , user Clicks on Make and gets list of Model(which is a big list), so i need to scroll and select some thing down under -- its a car listing app   @Deepak_Mahalingam

Comment: are u able to inspect element in that scroll page ?? @Lokesh

Comment: Yes see the attached screen shot

Answer (score 0):

use driver.swipe instead of driver.scroll

http://automationbyharsh.blogspot.in/

visit this blog to get full documentation of swipe method for Android and IOS.

Answer (score 0):

scrollTO method is not consistent in appium for android apps. so try the following.
go till model listing page

try the below code snippet , This was for flipkart app
it may help you with your app

driver.findElementById("com.flipkart.android:id/search_autoCompleteTextView").sendKeys("Reebok Shoes" +"\n");
        Thread.sleep(8000);

```
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    System.out.println(size);

    int Starty=(int)(size.height*0.90);
    int Endy=(int)(size.height*0.10);

    int Startx=(int)(size.width*0.50);


    WebElement ele_item = driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.TextView");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    do
    {

        List<WebElement> ele_item2 = driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@index='2'][@text='Reebok SPEED XT Running Shoes'][@class='android.widget.TextView']");
        int size2 = ele_item2.size();
        System.out.println(size2);

        if(size2>0)
        {
            driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@index='2'][@text='Reebok SPEED XT Running Shoes'][@class='android.widget.TextView']").click();
            break;
        }


        driver.swipe(Startx, Starty, Startx, Endy, 1000);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

    } while(ele_item.isDisplayed()==true);
```